# $\det(aI-T) = 0$ implies $a$ is an eigenvalue of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

In Hoffman and Kunze's *linear algebra*, right after the definition of an eigenvalue for an endomorphism $T: V \to V$ (i.e. $a\in F$ is an eigenvalue if there exists $\alpha\in V$, $\alpha \neq 0$, such that $T\alpha = a\cdot \alpha$) there is a theorem that states the equivalence of three conditions:

1. $a$ is an eigenvalue of $T$
2. $aI-T$ is singular
3. $\det (aI-T) = 0$

I understand $1 \Rightarrow 2 \Rightarrow 3$, but I'm unable to understand the argument that underlies 3 $\Rightarrow$ 1, the book states (and I paraphrase):

> If the space $V$ is of finite dimension, then $aI - T$ is non-injective just when its determinant is 0

I know that, if $aI - T$ is non-injective, the existence of an $\alpha$ such that $(aI - T)(\alpha) = 0$ (and, therefore, $T\alpha = a\cdot \alpha$) follows, but I don't understand the relation between $\det(aI-T)$ and the *non-injectivity* of $aI-T$. **Any hints?**

Comment: Well, one could prove it in another easier way. $2\iff 3$ isn't that bad, and $1\iff 2$ would do just fine, am I right?

Comment: Denote by $a_1,...,a_n$ the columns of $aI-T$. If the determinant is zero then the columns of the matrix are linearly dependent. This means that there are $x_1,...,x_n$ not all zero such that $x_1a_1+...+x_na_n=0$. If $x$ is a vector with components $x_1,...,x_n$ then $x_1a_1+...+x_na_n=(aI-T)x$. Therefore $(aI-T)x=0$, with $x\neq0$. The equivalence with the non-injectivity (probably) passes through this argument, so it is not really needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\det(aI-T)\neq 0$ is equivalent to $aI-T$  is invertible, hence $(aI-T)\cdot\alpha=0$ implies $\alpha=0$, which means injectivity for linear mappings.

Comment: Very nice, thanks. So, the finite dimension of $V$ doesn't really matter?, or what am I losing?

Comment: What is a determinant if the dimension is not finite?

Comment: V has to be of finite dimension so that we could talk about its matrix representation, is that correct?

Comment: Infinite matrix also exist (in analysis) but I've never heard of determinants for endomorphisms of infinite dimensional vector spaces;

Comment: Might be relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/126464/is-there-an-analog-of-determinant-for-linear-operators-in-infinite-dimensions-as

Answer (score -2):

A matrix $M$ has $\det M = 0$ if and only if that matrix is not invertible.  Thinking of $M$ as a linear transformation, that it's not invertible means it either fails to be injective or it fails to be surjective.  But the rank-nullity theorem will tell you that because the dimensions of the domain and codomain are equal, failing to be surjective *implies* that it also fails to be injective.  So either way it's not injective.

Comment: This is not proving anything, only re-stating the same claim as in the book the OP quoted.

Comment: @Tom: This fills in intermediate steps, with considerably more detail than the accepted answer.

Comment: This takes a huge detour to deduce non-injectivity using a completely unnecessary theorem and ends up not filling any more details than the accepted answer. The only missing detail in the accepted answer is saying that $u\neq v$ with $Mu=Mv$ (non-injectivity) is equivalent to $M(u-v)=0$, i.e. $Mx=0$ has non-zero solutions.

Comment: Yes, indeed you're supposing that I know that "$[T]_B $ is singular $\iff$ $T$ is singular". And that is precisely the question.